# Find and use duplicate element in array php mysql

Tags: php

I have merged two arrays with a total of 6 elements

`$merge = (array_merge($a1,$a2));`

I want to find the duplicate values and use this information to call and attach a specific image to those values within a table

```
foreach($merge as $data => $data_array){
   $search_data = array_search($data_array, $merge);
   if ($data != $search_data) {
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td ><img src="img/youAreNotDuplicated.png" width="85px" height="85px"></img></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '</table>';
        }else{
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td ><img src="img/youAreDuplicated.png" width="85px" height="85px"></img></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '</table>';
        }
}
```

The problem is I end up with 7 images instead of 6. The duplicated value is added to the table. How do I remove the duplicated value from my table without altering the array.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_diff, but this way will be more faster:

```
$cnt_array = array_count_values($merge)
foreach($cnt_array as $key=>$val){
   if($val == 1){
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td ><img src="img/youAreNotDuplicated.png" width="85px" height="85px"></img></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '</table>';
   }
   else{
            echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td ><img src="img/youAreDuplicated.png" width="85px" height="85px"></img></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '</table>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome and thank you. The tables is out of order though. With the duplicate images starting at the beginning. Is there a way to keep the order? The array is 1,2,3,4,5,6. But comes out 3,1,2,4,5,6 in this example. 3 being the duplicate value.

Comment: I used ksort($cnt_array) to sort the array before the loop